# Slow mysql query using Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

To filter the products that belongs to the selected filters, I wrote this query below. When i run this in Mysql, it is very fast. But when i'm trying to execute this query in Doctrine, it is very slow. Removing the group by gives me one result and than it is fast, but it has to be 11 results.

Even the more filters i add to this statement, the slower it gets.

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

```sql
    SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.brand_id, p.name, p.permalink, p.base_model, 
    p.ean, p.description, p.unit, p.price, p.offer_active, p.offer_price, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT m.url ORDER BY `m`.`order`, `p`.`id` SEPARATOR ",") AS url, pcm.category_id 
    FROM product p 
    LEFT JOIN product_category pc ON pc.product_id = p.id 
    LEFT JOIN media m ON p.id = m.product_id 
    INNER JOIN product_category pcm ON p.id = pcm.product_id AND pcm.main = 1 AND pcm.product_id IS NOT NULL 
    LEFT JOIN product_filter_value pfv1 ON p.id = pfv1.product_id 
    LEFT JOIN product_filter_value pfv2 ON p.id = pfv2.product_id 
    LEFT JOIN product_filter_value pfv3 ON p.id = pfv3.product_id 
    LEFT JOIN product_filter_value pfv4 ON p.id = pfv4.product_id 
    WHERE (pc.category_id = 23) 
    AND (p.active = 1) 
    AND (pfv1.filter_value_id IN (2)) 
    AND (pfv2.filter_value_id IN (8)) 
    AND (pfv3.filter_value_id IN (22)) 
    AND (pfv4.filter_value_id IN (38)) 
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY p.top desc
```

Comment: I think you're running the query when it's cached, that's why it's fast in mysql , can you try to give us some more info run EXPLAIN [you query]

Comment: @angel.bonev I already solved my problem. The problem in my statement was the group by even as the join on my media table. Now it's loading fast again.Thanks for your response!